# Transform/traverse Shapeless' HMap

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

Shapeless' `HListOps` includes a number of [useful functions](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala) for their heterogeneous `HList` type. I couldn't find an equivalent for `HMap`.

Here is my goal. I have a simple `Map[String, String]` which is used as an options repository in the pipeline of message processing in quite a few places of my application. I now would like to add a different `(Key => Value)` to this map, by transforming it to a HMap, so it could be something like:

```scala
class HOptionsMap[K, V]
implicit val intToString = new HOptionsMap[String, String]
implicit val stringToInt = new HOptionsMap[String, Instant]
```

So I could further use it as follows:

```scala
val hm = HMap[HOptionsMap]("placeOfIncident" -> "Toronto", "incidentDate" -> Instant.now)
```

Except I would like to call operations like `collect, fold, filter` on the above, which are not supported (unlike with `HList`). This is a requirement in order to not break current functionality.

Of course I could use composition here but I would be curious if this would be achievable with Shapeless library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HMap` is an inconvenient abstraction for your use case try to use a record

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

val hm = "placeOfIncident" ->> "Toronto" :: "incidentDate" ->> Instant.now :: HNil
```

You can collect, fold, filter it as any HList/record.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records